# React clarifications

Tags: reactjs, express

I am trying to understand React to possibly create an app for Production purposes.

I am used to creating an Node Express app, and with Express if we want https we require https and in the https.createserver() we provide a path to our pem file from our CA and our passphrase to access it.

Do we not have this option to use a CA Certificate file for React?  Or since it is just a UI does it not need it?

Say I have an Express API, I created using https that I can get information from using postman with no problems, and I want my React App to access my API.  Is the only thing I will need to get info from my api the proxy line in my react package.json file pointing to https://api.to.call.com? I thought it was bad practiced to post or get to https server from http.

Plus I just read that Create-React-App should not be used for production.  Then what am I supposed to use for production?  Is there a Create-React-Production-App? Or is this something else I need to add to my express server?  I am very confused about the entire setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is a front-end library. As such, it has nothing to do with SSL certificates, since in the end it's just javascript code that runs inside the client interface (i.e. a browser).

React is also agnostic when it comes to your back-end. It can be Node/Express, Rails, Python, PHP, your front-end really doesn't care, all it will see is an API that provides data (usually in the JSON form) upon request.

You do not have to serve your API and your front-end files from the same server - you *can*, but it's a matter of preference. And to access your API from your front-end, you can use one of several npm packages, [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is a great one, there are others (Fetch, ...) ; all you have to do is hookup your API calls using the same URLs you used in Postman in the components that require them.

As for Create-React-App, it's a nice helper tool, but I would recommend learning a bit about the React ecosystem rather than rely blindly on it. The trickiest part is probably the Webpack configuration, but once you get the hang of it, everything becomes a lot easier. There are also newer tools like [poi](https://github.com/egoist/poi) that can do a lot of the grunt work for you. With Webpack, you can have a dev configuration (hot reloading dev server, etc.) and a production configuration (that will output your production build JS, HTML, CSS, can optimize with chunking, etc.).

I'm not very familiar with Create-React-App (I prefer to use my own boilerplate projects), but if I'm not mistaken, there is a possibility for you to access full customization of your project, [see here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#converting-to-a-custom-setup). Be warned however, it's a one-way operation.